# Python AppEngine Sort By Referenced Property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sorting, google-cloud-datastore

I have a model Entry

```
class Entry(db.Model):
    year = db.StringProperty()
    .
    .
    .
```

and for whatever reason the last name field is stored in a different model LastName:

```
class LastName(db.Model):
    entry = db.ReferenceProperty(Entry, collection_name='last_names')
    last_name = db.StringProperty()
```

If I query Entry and sort it by year (or any other property) using `.order()` how would I then sort that by the last name? I'm new to python but coming from Java I would guess there's some kind of comparator equivalent; or I'm completely wrong and there's another way to do it. I for sure cannot change my model at this point in time, though that may be the solution later. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I'm currently paginating through the results using offsets (moving to cursors soon, but I think it would be the same issue). So if I try to sort outside of the datastore I would only be sorting the current set; it's possible that the first page will be all 'B's and the second page will have 'A's, so it will only be sorted by page not by overall set. Am I screwed the way my models are currently set up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GqlQuery OrderBy a property in a ReferenceProperty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514450/gqlquery-orderby-a-property-in-a-referenceproperty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues here.

There's no way to do this sorting directly in the datastore API, either in Python or Java - as you no doubt know, the datastore is non-relational, and indirect lookups like this aren't supported.

If this was just a straight one-to-one relationship, which gave you an accessor from the `Entry` entity to the `LastName` one, you could use the standard Python `sort` function to sort the list:

```
entries.sort(key=lambda e: e.last_name.last_name)
```

(note that this sorts the list in place but returns None, so don't try assigning from it).

However, this won't work, because what you've actually got here is a one-to-many relationship: there are potentially many LastNames for each Entry. The definition actually recognises this: the `collection_name` attribute, which defines the accessor from Entry to LastName, is called `last_names`, ie plural.

So what you're asking doesn't really make sense: which of the potentially many LastNames do you want to sort on? You can certainly do it the other way round - given a query of LastNames, sort by entry year - but given your current structure there's not really any way of doing it.

I must say though, although I don't know the rest of your models, I suspect you have actually got that relationship the wrong way round: the `ReferenceProperty` should probably live on `Entry` pointing to `LastName` rather than the other way round as it is now. Then it would simply be the sort call I gave above.

Comment: It's a very weird schema (is that term use in GAE?). The Entry class is actually where all the main information I need lives (there's more than just the year property). This app is a work in progress so as I learn more about GAE I make corrections. That being said, at this point I need to sort on only the first last name in the last_names collection.

Comment: @Eliezer Which is the 'first'? There's no natural order for entities other than key, which is arbitrary. In any case, this should almost certainly not be a separate property, but rather a list property on the original Entry.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it should just arbitrarily pull one last name from the collection and sort on that. I know its a little weird but which name it pulls doesn't matter as long as its sorting something. Either way I think I'm going to add it as a list property in Entry. Thanks!